# Missing catalina.out in tomcat9

Tags: docker, tomcat

I'm git clone https://github.com/fjudith/docker-draw.io.git

This file contains tomcat: 9-jre8-alpine in the dockerfile.

I installed as instructed.

but When I try to check the log, catalina.log exists by date and catalina.out does not exist.

/bin/catalina.sh

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then                                   
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out                               
fi 


////


touch "$CATALINA_OUT"                                                         
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then                                              
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then                                                
      echo "Using Security Manager"                                             
    fi                                                                          
    shift                                                                       
    eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OP
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \                              
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \                                             
      -Djava.security.manager \                                                 
      -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \       
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \                                    
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \                                    
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \                                 
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \                        
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"                                               

  else                                                                          
    eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OP
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \                              
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \                                             
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \                                    
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \                                    
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \                                 
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \                        
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"                                               

  fi
```

As I see it looks normal.

I don't know why not.

Can you let me know if you know?

Comment: Did you not see any logs in `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs` directory ?

Comment: Thank you but The log exists. But I want to check console.log. So you need catalina.out